# Java jFrame canvas draws dots instead of lines

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, java-canvas

I've been wanting to design a generator for dragon curves.

(If you want info on that check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) out, but it doesn't really matter for the issue)

A dragon curve is a repeating mathematical construct.
I've already written a generator for what the canvas should draw, it works by returning a char array consisting of 'r' or 'l', saying whether the line has to turn left or right next. In the code here, it's the method `input()`. This part works perfectly.

The problem is that whenever I want to draw it on the canvas (using `drawLine`), it only draws the first two lines as actual lines, the rest are just dots.

The dots are on the right positions and if you make the thing really big, you can't tell the difference anymore, but nevertheless, there are supposed to be lines there.

Image:
[image: imgur]

This is the code I used:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;




/**
  *
  * Description
  *
  * @version 1.0 from 4/20/2016
  * @author 
  */

public class CurveGen extends JFrame {
  // start attributes
  private Canvas display = new Canvas();
  private JButton startButton = new JButton();
  private JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
  private JTextArea outText = new JTextArea("");
    private JScrollPane outTextScrollPane = new JScrollPane(outText);
  private JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
  private JSlider xSlider = new JSlider();
  private JSlider ySlider = new JSlider();
  private JNumberField iterationsNF = new JNumberField();
  private JNumberField sizeNF = new JNumberField();
  // end attributes




  public CurveGen(String title) { 
    // Frame-Init
    super(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    int frameWidth = 1022; 
    int frameHeight = 731;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setResizable(false);
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    // start components

    display.setBounds(16, 64, 601, 601);
    cp.add(display);
    startButton.setBounds(736, 464, 241, 129);
    startButton.setText("START!");
    startButton.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        startButton_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    startButton.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 36));
    cp.add(startButton);
    jLabel1.setBounds(760, 96, 75, 41);
    jLabel1.setText("Iterations:");
    cp.add(jLabel1);
    outTextScrollPane.setBounds(728, 392, 257, 57);
    cp.add(outTextScrollPane);
    jLabel2.setBounds(768, 144, 67, 41);
    jLabel2.setText("Size:");
    cp.add(jLabel2);
    xSlider.setBounds(0, 8, 633, 49);
    xSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(25);
    xSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
    xSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    xSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    xSlider.setToolTipText("Starting point y-coordinate");
    xSlider.setMaximum(600);
    xSlider.setValue(300);
    cp.add(xSlider);
    ySlider.setBounds(624, 56, 65, 625);
    ySlider.setMinorTickSpacing(25);
    ySlider.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
    ySlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    ySlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    ySlider.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    ySlider.setMaximum(600);
    ySlider.setInverted(true);
    ySlider.setValue(300);
    ySlider.setToolTipText("Starting point x-coordinate");
    cp.add(ySlider);
    iterationsNF.setBounds(856, 96, 81, 41);
    iterationsNF.setText("");
    cp.add(iterationsNF);
    sizeNF.setBounds(856, 144, 81, 41);
    sizeNF.setText("");
    cp.add(sizeNF);
    // end components

    setVisible(true);
  } // end of public CurveGen

  // start methods

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CurveGen("CurveGen");



  } // end of main

  public char[] input(int iter) {         
    char oldOut[] = new char[0];            
    for (int i=1;i<=iter;i++) {
      char newOut[] = new char[((int)Math.pow(2, i))-1];
      for (int n=0;n<oldOut.length;n++) {
        newOut[n] = oldOut[n];
        if (oldOut[n]=='r') {
          newOut[newOut.length-n-1] = 'l';
        }
        if (oldOut[n]=='l') {
          newOut[newOut.length-n-1] = 'r';
        } // end of if
      } // end of for
      newOut[oldOut.length]='l';      
      oldOut = newOut; 
    } // end of for        
    return oldOut;
  }  



  public void startButton_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {


    int iterations = iterationsNF.getInt();
    int size = sizeNF.getInt();

    char com[] = input(iterations);
    outText.setText(String.valueOf(com));

    int dir = 0;
    int newDir = 0;
    int lastPos[] = {xSlider.getValue(),ySlider.getValue()-size};
    int newPos[] = {0,0};

    Graphics g = display.getGraphics();

    g.clearRect(0,0,601,601);
    g.drawLine(xSlider.getValue(),ySlider.getValue(),xSlider.getValue(),ySlider.getValue()-size);


    for (int i=0;i<=com.length-1;i++) {
      dir = newDir;
      if (dir==0) {
        if (com[i]=='l') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0]-size;
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1];
          newDir = 3;
        } 
        if (com[i]=='r') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0]+size;
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1];
          newDir = 1;
        }              
      } 
      if (dir==1) {
        if (com[i]=='l') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0];
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1]-size;
          newDir = 0;
        } 
        if (com[i]=='r') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0];
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1]+size;
          newDir = 2;
        }              
      } 
      if (dir==2) {
        if (com[i]=='l') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0]+size;
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1];
          newDir = 1;
        } 
        if (com[i]=='r') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0]-size;
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1];
          newDir = 3;
        }              
      } 
      if (dir==3) {                                
        if (com[i]=='l') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0];
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1]+size;
          newDir = 2;
        } 
        if (com[i]=='r') {
          newPos[0] = lastPos[0];
          newPos[1] = lastPos[1]-size;
          newDir = 0;
        }              
      } 

      g.drawLine(lastPos[0],lastPos[1],newPos[0],newPos[1]);

      lastPos=newPos;
    } // end of for




  } // end of startButton_ActionPerformed

  // end methods
} // end of class CurveGen
```

Comment: As per the site [help] recommendations, please post your [mcve]. Also what is "display"? I hope it's a BufferedImage and not a Swing component.

Comment: `Graphics g = display.getGraphics();` scares me.  If you're using `JComponent#getGraphics`, then don't

Comment: "display" is the canvas that is being drawn on.

Comment: "canvas" has many meanings to many people, is it a `BufferedImage`, is it a `JPanel` or `JComponent` is it a `java.awt.Canvas` is it a `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas` ... See Hovercraft's comment, this is why we ask for MCVE, it removes assumtions and guess work

Comment: i see. it should be a Java.awt.canvas

Comment: i have edited it now to include the entire code.

Comment: Like what @HovercraftFullOfEels said, post minimal code that is complete and is sufficient that the question may be thoroughly understood and answerable

Comment: @liquid-7 Okay, using `getGraphics` in this way is a bad idea, mixing heavyweight (`java.awt.Canvas`) and lightweight (Swing) components is unadvisable. I would suggest having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done

Comment: im sorry about the mess. its my first post. thanks for still answering. ill try to get rid of the AWT

Comment: @liquid-7 Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've gone back over the code...

- Mixing heavyweight (`java.awt.Canvas`) and lightweight (Swing) components is unadvisable as they can cause or sorts of painting issues
- `getGraphics` is not how paint should be done.  Instead, I'd start with a custom `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent`. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
- Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

I believe the problem is associated with this...

```
lastPos=newPos;
```

All you are doing is making `lastPos` point to the same place in memory as `newPos`, so when you assign values to `newPos`, `lastPos` will have the same values, hence the reason you're seeing dots.

What I would do first, is separate the responsible for the generation of the data from the display.

I'd start with some kind of model (note, you could create a model which took `iterations` instead and which generated the data itself, but I was focusing on solving the initial problem)

```
public class DragonModel {

    private Point startPoint;
    private int size;
    private char[] values;

    public DragonModel(Point startPoint, int size, char[] values) {
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
        this.size = size;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Point getStartPoint() {
        return startPoint;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public char[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

}
```

and then the display...

```
public class DragonPane extends JPanel {

    private DragonModel model;

    public void setModel(DragonModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (model != null) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int size = model.getSize();
            int dir = 0;
            int newDir = 0;
            Point lastPos = model.getStartPoint();
            Point newPos = new Point(0, 0);

            for (char value : model.values) {
                if (dir == 0) {
                    if (value == 'l') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x - size;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y;
                        newDir = 3;
                    }
                    if (value == 'r') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x + size;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y;
                        newDir = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (dir == 1) {
                    if (value == 'l') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y - size;
                        newDir = 0;
                    }
                    if (value == 'r') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y + size;
                        newDir = 2;
                    }
                }
                if (dir == 2) {
                    if (value == 'l') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x + size;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y;
                        newDir = 1;
                    }
                    if (value == 'r') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x - size;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y;
                        newDir = 3;
                    }
                }
                if (dir == 3) {
                    if (value == 'l') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y + size;
                        newDir = 2;
                    }
                    if (value == 'r') {
                        newPos.x = lastPos.x;
                        newPos.y = lastPos.y - size;
                        newDir = 0;
                    }
                }
                g.drawLine(lastPos.x, lastPos.y, newPos.x, newPos.y);
                dir = newDir;
                lastPos = new Point(newPos);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The idea here is to try and decouple of the responsibility a little, the responsibility for the generation and displaying of the data sit firmly in two different areas.

Then in your `actionPerformed` method you could simply do...

```
public void startButton_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    int iterations = Integer.parseInt(iterationsNF.getText());
    int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeNF.getText());

    char com[] = input(iterations);
    outText.setText(String.valueOf(com));

    DragonModel model = new DragonModel(new Point(xSlider.getValue(), ySlider.getValue()), size, com);
    display.setModel(model);

} // end of startButton_ActionPerformed
```

which could result in something like...

[image: Dragons!]

Answer (score 0):

The drawing code should be inside the paint(Graphics) method to synchronize with the rendering loop properly. In an event handler, update the data model of the component (calculate the lines and keep them in a data structure inside the component), then call the method repaint() to trigger the event rendering loop, which will call your paint method.

There are some other variations of this, but the general idea is that you change the data and then request rendering. The rendering engine may call your paint method in other cases as well, not only when you change the data, so ideally paint() has all the data it needs to render fast, meaning it should not do calculations or heavy operations other than rendering on the Graphics object.

This means that you have to subclass JComponent in a new class, and implement paint inside it. This class should have an internal data structure with the lines ready to render at any point in time. Then use your new class in the JFrame.